# Optimizing c++ compiliation for a specific machine

Tags: compiling, c++

I am programming a code to simulate a membrane which will run on computation cluster (single node). I want to optimize the code for that machine. I have used the -optimize, -O3 and -march=core2.

How can I tell if I can improve the march factor and is there any other thing I can do to improve this?

thanks

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Wait, I thought you meant GCC, but **`-optimize`**? What compiler has such option?

Comment: I am using g++. I have placed it there after reading this in some documentation (the code compiles)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-mtune`. `-march` is used to determine the allowed instruction set, whereas `-mtune` is to be used to tune performance of the code (as always, see `man gcc`). Depending on the precise CPU type, you might also consider values other than `core2`. And if you use a recent GCC version (at least `4.4`, I think), you might best use `native` instead.

Comment: How can I tell which cpu type I have? I tried to use the native switch but the compiler doesn't know this...

Comment: On the system-side, `cat /proc/cpuinfo` will give you enough information. Using this, you can google for `-march`/`-mtune` recommendations. But a better option might be to just upgrade your GCC and use `-march=native -mtune=native`.

Comment: upgrading gcc is not an option since I am not the root of the machine (or the cluster).

Comment: I have a 4 core processor with: ``model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         860  @ 2.80GHz``. I tried to use corei7 but it won't compile. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html

Comment: Better first read what you are referring to. The source you linked states clearly that *[It corresponds to the compilers (GCC) version 4.7.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/index.html#Top)*. If `native` does not work, it must be a few years old, much older than the processor. Ask the administrator for an update if you really need such top performance.

Comment: Thanks, sorry. The man files ends with: ``gcc-4.1.2                         2011-01-13 ``

Comment: This is a huge discrepancy then. Talk to the administrator. Maybe there already is a more recent GCC, but not used by default. If you must stick with this one, ask a separate question for the "core i7 vs gcc-4.1" dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to read the manual for your compiler and look at the optimisation options.  Note that some optimisation will not give you much, so you must test your code after it has been compiled.  Note that you may notice bugs in the code depending on what options you choose.

If you use icc, you can make sure of some #pragma options in the code to paralelise some loops.

Answer (score 1):

If your computations involve many vectors, you may want to consider the [Intel Math Library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/). A project I am on for work uses it and they swear by it.